# Is it alright to return a reference to a non-pointer member variable as a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, reference, smart-pointers

I recently came across some C++ code that looked like this:

```
class SomeObject
{
private:
    // NOT a pointer
    BigObject foobar;

public:
    BigObject * getFoobar() const
    {
        return &foobar;
    }
};
```

I asked the programmer why he didn't just make foobar a pointer, and he said that this way he didn't have to worry about allocating/deallocating memory. I asked if he considered using some smart pointer, he said this worked just as well.

Is this bad practice? It seems very hackish.

Comment: I don't see any issues with this. I wouldn't really do this, but still I do not see any real problem with it.

Comment: expression `&foobar` is not reference, it's address of member

Comment: Pointers are generally bad. In this case, the code doesn't even compile, but returning a const reference would have been entirely appropriate.

Comment: Without more info, I'd say a smart pointer here would be either *pointless* (if something like  `unique_ptr` is used) or *lazy* (if some `shared_ptr` is used).

Comment: You couldn't "just" make it a pointer; you'd also have to make sure it points to something, and manage the lifetime of that object.

Comment: It is not hackish. It is stupid. He could just put it in the public section. btw he returns non-const pointer from a const member function

Comment: @BЈовић: In the case of this simple example, you're right; but often you want to only grant read-only access, or check and maintain invariants when it's accessed, in which case you do want it to be private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this bad practice? It seems very hackish.

It is. If the class goes out of scope before the pointer does, the member variable will no longer exist, yet a pointer to it still exists. Any attempt to dereference that pointer post class destruction will result in undefined behaviour - this could result in a crash, or it could result in hard to find bugs where arbitrary memory is read and treated as a BigObject.

> if he considered using some smart pointer

Using smart pointers, specifically `std::shared_ptr<T>` or the boost version, would technically work here and avoid the potential crash (if you allocate via the shared pointer constructor) - however, it also confuses who owns that pointer - the class, or the caller? Furthermore, I'm not sure you can just add a pointer to an object to a smart pointer.

Both of these two points deal with the technical issue of getting a pointer out of a class, but the real question should be "why?" as in "why are you returning a pointer from a class?" There are cases where this is the only way, but more often than not you don't need to return a pointer. For example, suppose that variable needs to be passed to a C API which takes a pointer to that type. In this case, you would probably be better encapsulating that C call in the class.

Comment: "Any attempt to dereference that pointer post class destruction will result in a segmentation fault" - unlikely, since freeing memory very rarely results in it becoming physically inaccessible. You'll probably get worse than a segfault -- the code will carry on running but do the wrong thing.

Comment: @Steve well, that might happen also... I just wanted to avoid "carry on running" as an explanation in case the OP didn't read any further than those three words.

Comment: Personally I'd say, "has undefined behavior", and field the question "what's that?" as and when it arises ;-) I'm keen not to give people the false impression that when they make this mistake they'll get a segfault, because if they have that impression then when they *don't* get a segfault they'll conclude that they *haven't* made this mistake.

Answer (score 6):

That's perfectly reasonable, and not "hackish" in any way; although it might be considered better to return a reference to indicate that the object definitely exists. A pointer might be null, and might lead some to think that they should delete it after use.

The object has to exist somewhere, and existing as a member of an object is usually as good as existing anywhere else. Adding an extra level of indirection by dynamically allocating it separately from the object that owns it makes the code less efficient, and adds the burden of making sure it's correctly deallocated.

Of course, the member function can't be `const` if it returns a non-`const` reference or pointer to a member. That's another advantage of making it a member: a `const` qualifier on `SomeObject` applies to its members too, but doesn't apply to any objects it merely has a pointer to.

The only danger is that the object might be destroyed while someone still has a pointer or reference to it; but that danger is still present however you manage it. Smart pointers can help here, if the object lifetimes are too complex to manage otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a pointer to a member variable not a reference. This is bad design. 
Your class manages the lifetime of **foobar** object and by returning a pointer to its members you enable the consumers of your class to keep using the pointer beyond the lifetime of **SomeObject** object. And also it enables the users to change the state of **SomeObject** object as they wish.

Instead you should refactor your class to include the operations that would be done on the foobar in SomeObject class as methods.

ps. Consider naming your classes properly. When you define it is a class. When you instantiate, then you have an object of that class.

Comment: +1 for pointing out bad naming. C++ is hard anyway and even more confusing with strange names.

Comment: I'm sure the names `BigObject`, `SomeObject` and `foobar` are simply placeholders to make up the example.

Comment: `SomeObject` is as reasonable a placeholder class name as `Object` is a real class name. Certain languages I could mention do use `Object` as a class name, so you should take the matter up with James Gosling and with Anders Hejlsberg :-)

Comment: @Martinho: Hence the 'consider' part, I'm not advocating it; something to note when naming.

Comment: I don't think the distinction between a class and an object is significantly different in C++ from the same distinction in Java or in C#. The reason there's no `std::object` isn't because of C++'s particular naming conventions, it's simply because there's no ultimate superclass at all. I also don't think that naming classes after the objects they represent blurs the class/instance distinction. An object of type `vector` "is a vector". An object of type `SomeObject` "is some object". `Class` *can* appear in a placeholder classname like `MyClass`, but I think it's wrong to say that it *has* to.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally considered less than ideal to return pointers to internal data at all; it prevents the class from managing access to its own data. But if you want to do that anyway I see no great problem here; it simplifies the management of memory.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the caller knows that the pointer returned from `getFoobar()` becomes invalid when the `SomeObject` object destructs, it's fine. Such provisos and caveats are common in older C++ programs and frameworks.

Even current libraries have to do this for historical reasons. e.g. `std::string::c_str`, which returns a pointer to an internal buffer in the string, which becomes unusable when the string destructs.

Of course, that is difficult to ensure in a large or complex program. In modern C++ the preferred approach is to give everything simple "value semantics" as far as possible, so that every object's life time is controlled by the code that uses it in a trivial way. So there are no naked pointers, no explicit `new` or `delete` calls scattered around your code, etc., and so no need to require programmers to manually ensure they are following the rules.

(And then you can resort to smart pointers in cases where you are totally unable to avoid shared responsibility for object lifetimes.)

Comment: I sort of agree, but what would be the preferred modern C++ solution to the need for something like `std::string::c_str`, or for that matter `std::string::operator[]`? Getters and setters in place of references? Iterators that hold a `weak_ptr` to their parent container's internal data structure, so that they can safely check lifetime? Return a `shared_ptr` to some node that represents the nth element of the container, so the element can outlive the container if still in use? Maybe I'm just old, that I don't quite see how reference semantics can be wholly avoided ;-)

Comment: I am old too... and I agree that in C++ it's all something of a moot point. If you are writing system software in a flat address space, you need C++'s ability to talk directly to C APIs and fiddle with memory. If you're writing more high-level application code then you don't need any of those facilities, and you'd be better off without them... so why are you using C++? :)

Answer (score 0):

Two unrelated issues here:

1) How would you like your instance of `SomeObject` to manage the instance of `BigObject` that it needs? If each instance of `SomeObject` needs its own `BigObject`, then a `BigObject` data member is totally reasonable. There are situations where you'd want to do something different, but unless that situation arises stick with the simple solution.

2) Do you want to give users of `SomeObject` direct access to its `BigObject`? By default the answer here would be "no", on the basis of good encapsulation. But if you do want to, then that doesn't change the assessment of (1). Also if you do want to, you don't necessarily need to do so via a pointer -- it could be via a reference or even a public data member.

A third possible issue might arise that does change the assessment of (1):

3) Do you want to give users of `SomeObject` direct access to an instance of `BigObject` that they continue using beyond the lifetime of the instance of `SomeObject` that they got it from? If so then of course a data member is no good. The proper solution might be `shared_ptr`, or for `SomeObject::getFooBar` to be a factory that returns a different `BigObject` each time it's called.

In summary:

- Other than the fact it doesn't compile (`getFooBar()` needs to return `const BigObject*`), there is no reason so far to suppose that this code is wrong. Other issues could arise that make it wrong.
- It might be better style to return `const &` rather than `const *`. Which you return has no bearing on whether `foobar` should be a `BigObject` data member.
- There is certainly no "just" about making `foobar` a pointer or a smart pointer -- either one would necessitate extra code to create an instance of `BigObject` to point to.